# Adding a Dojo Datagrid to a ZF Dojo_Form, how can I do it?

Tags: php, datagrid, dojo, zend-form

I have this Form with several subForms I'm using a tabContainer,
In one of them I have a button when clicked would like that in that "space" subForm
a datagrid would appear with some values.

Is it possible to do this, how?

I tried creating a datagrid View Helper but this didn't work properly the DataGrid does not show.

Code used:

> /**  * Description of DataGrid  *  * @author andref  * @version $Id$ 
>   */ class Zend_View_Helper_DataGrid {
>       private $_nameDG       = 'DefaultSt';
>
> ```
> private $_action     = '';
>
> private $_key        = '';
>
> private $_selectMode = "single";
>
> private $_fields     = array();
>
> private $_storage   = 'getall/';
>
> public function dataGrid($key, $action = null, $options = array() )
> {
>
>     if (count($options) > 0 ) {
>         if (array_key_exists("selectmode", $options)) {
>             $this->_selectMode = $options['selectmode'];
>         } elseif (array_key_exists("fields", $options)) {
>             if (!is_array($options['fields'])) {
>                 throw new Exception("fields is not an array");
>             }
>             $this->_fields = $options['fields'];
>         } elseif(array_key_exists("selectmode", $options)) {
>             $this->_selectMode = $options['selectmode'];
>         } elseif(array_key_exists("storage", $options)) {
>                 $this->_storage = $options['storage'];
>         }
>     }
>
>     if ($action !== null ) {
>         $this->_action = $action;
>     }
>
>     if ($key === null ) {
>         throw new Exception("Key cannot be null.");
>     }
>
>     $this->_key = $key;
>
>     return $this->_init();
> }
>
> private function _init()
> {
>     $str = '';
>     if (!empty($this->_action)) {
>         $str .= $this->addJS();
>     }
>
>     $str .= $this->storageType();
>
>     $str .= $this->draw();
>
>     return $str;
> }
> /**
>  * Returns double click handler to direct to a form
>  * 
>  * @return String
>  */
> public function addJS()
> {
>     $str = "<script type=\"text/Javascript\">\n";
>     $str .= "function pickit(event)\n";
>     $str .= "{\n";
>     $str .= "grid = dijit.byId('grid".$this->_key."');\n";
>   $str .= "selected_index = grid.focus.rowIndex;\n";
>   $str .= "selected_item = grid.getItem(selected_index);\n";
>   //Not sure if this is the most efficient way but it worked for me
>   $str .= "selected_id = grid.store.getValue(selected_item, \"".$this->_key."\");\n";
>   $str .= "location.href = " . $this->_action . "+selected_id;\n";
>     $str .= "}\n";
>     $str .= "</script>\n";
>
>     return $str;
> }
>
> public function storageType()
> {
>     if (strpos($this->_storage, "[") !== false ) {
>         $st = "jsonData".$this->_key . " = " . $this->_storage."\n";
>         $st .= "<gett dojoType=\"dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore\" 
>             jsId=\"jsonStore" . $this->_key . "\" 
>                 data=\"jsonData" . $this->_key . "\" id=\"store" . $this->_key . "\" />";
>     } else {
>         $st = '<gett dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId=\"jsonStore'.$this->_key.'" 
>      url="' . $this->_storage . '" id="store'.$this->_key.'" />';
>     }
>
>     return $st;
> }
>
> public function draw()
> {
>     $str = '';
>     $str .= "<table dojoType=\"dojox.grid.DataGrid\" id=\"grid".$this->_key."\" jsid=\"gridJ".$this->_key."\" 
>    query=\"{ " . $this->_key . ": '*' }\" store=\"jsonStore".$this->_key."\"
>    selectionMode=\"" . $this->_selectMode . "\" autoWidth=\"true\"
>    style=\"width: 100%; height: 400px\" onRowDblClick='pickit();'>\n";
>     $str .= "<thead>\n";
>     $str .= "<tr>\n";
>     foreach ($this->_fields as $k => $v ) {
>         $str .= "\t<th field=\"$k\">$v</th>\n";
>     }
>     $str .= "</tr>\n";;
>     $str .= "</thead>\n";
>     $str .= "</table>\n";
>
>     return $str;
> }
>      }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try creating a grid in pure js and place it
using grid.placeat("idOfElement") in your element. Take a look here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html